# ODBC: how to handle Booleans?

Tags: odbc

Disclaimer: I am a n00b.

It seems like ODBC does not support a BOOLEAN type? Is this true?

If so, what's the standard kludgearound?

---

Edit:  I am using ADO with Delphi on Windows to write the data, but PHP 5 to read it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL itself has traditionally not supported a boolean type, so ODBC is just reflecting this. As ODBC is intended to provide portability across databases, it is generally better to implement booleans in the database as one of the standard types, such as CHAR(1), containing either 'Y' or 'N', rather than use a vendor specific type.

Comment: Thanks, Neil, that seems sensible (and somehow 'better' than using 0 or 1).

Comment: I don't agree.  ODBC is a C API, so it's easier (though not necessary) to use 0 and 1.

Comment: @Matthew It is techically no easier, Y and N are (for english speakers) self-documenting, and an integer takes up more space in the database.

Comment: @Neil, you can use a CHAR(1) with the integral values \1 and \0.  I would say this is self-documenting for C programmers.  I consider `if(lightOn)` more natural than `if(lightOn == 'Y')`.

Comment: @Matthew SQL databases are accessed by all sorts of programmers, not just C ones. and note that in C the character constants '1' and '0' are both true.

Comment: @Neil, ODBC is still a C API.  Other languages that use it have C wrappers.  It's also easy to use C-style booleans in most languages even if you need a `!= 0`.  I never said '0' and '1', I said \0 and \1.  I.E the literal byte values 0 and 1, NUL and Start of Heading. :)

Comment: @Mathew And those  will display nicely when you use a query tool will they? Give me a break.

Answer (score 1):

There's SQL_C_BIT, but you need to lookup what a given driver uses for each SQL type.  For example, [MySQL uses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-reference-datatypes.html) SQL_C_CHAR for bool.

Comment: +1 I am using ADO with Delphi on Windows to write the data, but PHP 5 to read it back.

Comment: But what driver?  For example, MySQL's is MySQL Connector/ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on the actual SQL server implementation. You can check the ODBC driver/datasource settings, if you are doing it under Windows -- there might be options such as Bool As Char, or something.

Comment: +1 but, "I believe it depends on the actual SQL server implementation" - surely that's what ODBC hides from me? Matthew might be closer to the mark when speaking of the driver(?)